# How to properly terminate thread if the exit function was called in main?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to create a module that uses a long-running thread. But if a client program calls `exit()` while the thread is running, the process hangs. How can I make it safe for the client to `exit()`?

Here's the code for my module:

```py
from threading import Lock, Thread
import signal
import time
import atexit

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__update_thread = Thread(target=self.__update)
        self.__signals_mutex = Lock()
        self.__update_thread_alive = True
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.at_exit)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.at_exit)
        self.__update_thread.start()

    def at_exit(self, a=None, b=None):
        print('at_exit called')
        self.__update_thread_alive = False
        self.__update_thread.join()
    
    def __del__(self):
        self.at_exit()

    def __update(self):
        while self.__update_thread_alive:
            #do_stuff
            time.sleep(0.01)

__test = Test()

atexit.register(__test.at_exit)
```

Why after importing this module and then calling `exit()` function the interpreter [freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42rXD.png) both in `Windows` and `Linux`?  And when I'm just [executing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq2xE.png).

This is caused by a thread, obviously. I guess `exit()` just joins the `__update_thread`.

So the main question is: how should I get a signal to terminate it without removing a global variable and caring about it outside of the module?

Comment: I added a lede to your question so that people can see, up-front, what you are asking. Feel free to revert my edit if I got it wrong.

Comment: P.S., Why does your `at_exit()` method call `...is_alive()`? Why not just `join()` the thread? `join()` doesn't _do_ anything. It just returns if and when the thread has finished. It's perfectly safe to call `join()` on a thread that is not alive. And in fact, your code, as written, doesn't actually guarantee that the thread _is_ alive when `join()` is called. The thread could have died _after_ `is_alive()` returned `True`, but before `join()` was called.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yep, you're right. thanks

Comment: I tried running variations on your program, and it looks to me as if your `at_exit()` method is not called. The `sys.exit()` function supposedly just throws `SystemExit`. I am not a Python wizard, and I don't know what the default handler for `SystemExit` does, but that seems like the place to look. Unfortunately, [documentation for SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) doesn't seem to say anything about how it deals with "background" threads.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think I will just use `multiprocessing` to do this but thank you for your time.